# bindIp not working on ubuntu 16 for MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have mongoDb installed on ubuntu ec2 instance and want to allow the connection from other multiple IP, I tried bindIp but it is not working. Following is the code I have in the conf file

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 10.0.1.1,10.0.1.2
```

I tried following too but none of them worked

```
bindIp: "10.0.1.1,10.0.1.2"
bindIp: [10.0.1.1,10.0.1.2]
```

Other posts in stackoverflow or tutorials suggests one of them, I am not sure why it is not working for me. following is the error I get

```
mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

can someone help me to get it started with multiple ips

Comment: Better use `localhost` instead of `10.0.1.1,10.0.1.2` - that are private IP's, actually they many change at any time.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit doesn't the localhost open the connection from all ? is it safe ?

Comment: It's safe, it allows only connections from the host where the MongoDB is running. In order to permit connection from any host use `bindIpAll: true `

Comment: ok, then how will it allow the connection specific other server for which I am trying to bind multiple ips

Comment: trying to setup replication or different ec2 instances

Comment: Read the server log for the error message.